# ERROR with Ubuntu: Cannot open the disk 'D:\My Documents\My Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-1.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on

Tags: vmware

Cannot open the disk 'D:\My Documents\My Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-1.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

Reason: The physical disk is already in use.

======================

When I powered on my Ubuntu on VMwave, a window showed up within words above. I tried to remove the old hard disk in settings and created a new one, but it still doesnot work.

Also, I tried to delete the .lck files and even the doc.  BUT.......

Has someone solved this problem? PLEASE do me a favour!!Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to logout and login again or restart, maybe virtual hard disk is still in use by any application somehow.

Comment: THX!!! I tried but doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

There might be a virtual hard drive (RDM drive) which would be unavailable during VM startup. Try removing the drive and start the VM. Hope it may help.